# Why is the move constructor not called when initializing std::vector with const char literals?

Tags: c++, stdvector, move-semantics

I understand that when initialization occurs with rvalues, the move constructor should be called if it is implemented. Therefore, I expected the move constructor to be called for the following code with the compiler options "-fno-elide-constructors -Qn" (for the purpose of disable copy elision):

```
std::vector<std::string> my_vec {"hello", "world"};
```

However, copy constructors are being called for "hello" and "world". Why is this happening?

Best regards.

Comment: Because the constructor with the initializer_list always involves copies.

Comment: Try real `std::string` literals: `std::vector<std::string> my_vec {"hello"s, "world"s};`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This will also invoke the copy constructor because the elements in a `std::initializer_list` are `const`

Comment: chrysante. This makes sense. const prevent calling move constructor. But i guess "Because the constructor with the initializer_list always involves copies. – 
273K"  is not true.

Comment: @SuatMutlu That is also true. Constructing a container from a `std::initializer_list` always involves copying the elements in the list because they are `const`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code, you are trying to create `std::vector` from `std::initializer_list`. `std::initializer_list` container gives access to its elements only by const references or pointers to const values. For this reason, you can not use move semantics, because you can not move from `const` value, because then you will need to assign default value, what is impossible here (because `const` is not modifiable). So you need to create copies of given strings. You will meet the same behaviour while using `std::set`, `std::map` and other associative containers with key of type `const T`.